# which of following are uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

which of the following are uniformly convergent?

1. $\frac{1}{n(1+x^2)}$ in $\mathbb{R}$
2. $\frac{sin~nx}{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$
3. $\frac{x^2+nx}{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$
4. $\frac{x^n}{n}$ in [0,1]

All except 3 is pointwise convergent and converges to 0. But to check uniform convergence Wiestrauss M-test is not working as 1/n is not absolutely convergent.
 I think these three are uniformly convergent. How to prove this

Comment: Wiestrauss M-test only applies to series of functions not sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (4).  It suffices to prove that the 'largest' separation from the terms in the sequence to the limit shrinks to zero to prove uniform convergence.

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$ and we consider the following supremum.
$$sup\{|f_n(x)|:x\in[0,1], n\in\mathbf{N}\}\leq sup\{|f_n(1)|: n\in\mathbf{N}\}= 0 $$ $
so the sequence much converge uniformly.  I recommend applying this method to the others.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: which result used here for telling the convergence is uniform?

Comment: the fact that a sequence converges uniformly iff it converges in the sup norm...